# How to remove all lines in file till a specific word occures PHP

Tags: php, file

I have multiple files containing the same text structure. I am now trying to remove all lines till a line starts with a specific word.
This a part of one of the files:

```
Test        Sampertant
ALL         5784
COMMENT     This files contains information about infomarxinc
COMMENT     Companie located in USA
FEATURES               Location/Qualifiers
     A               lines (7709..2170)
     3'try           complement(7676..7678)
                     /note="stop"
                     /label=STOP
     B               lines (7679..7708)
                     /note="stop"
                     /label=start
PAST
        1 talian and American multinational corporation and is the world’s 
       50 eighth largest auto maker.The group was established in late 2014
```

I want to keep only the lines after PAST 
I have written the following code to do this

```
$lines = file($newname);

# Loop through the array
foreach($lines as $line) { 

$seq = trim($line);

    # Find all lines starting with a number
    if (preg_match('/^\d/', $seq)){ 
        # Replace all number with | 
        $seq = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $seq);
        $seq = preg_replace('/\s/',"",$seq);

        # Store in string
        $out .= $seq;
    } 
### Read lines into file ###
    $f = fopen($newname, "w");
    fwrite($f, $out);
    fclose($f);
}
```

With most files it's working till I got this file. A line before PART started with 3'try. And in my end result the 3'try was also added but I didn't want that. **How can I now remove all lines till my line start with the line PAST and then carry out my code to find all lines starting with a number.** 
To only keep these lines for this file:

```
 1 talian and American multinational corporation and is the world’s 
 50 eighth largest auto maker.The group was established in late 2014
```

Comment: What do you mean by: *and then carry out my code to find all lines starting with a number*? and also PART or PAST ?

Comment: Suggestion: read the file line by line. Check every line for equality with `PAST\n`. Once that check succeeds, grab all lines after that. Done. No need for regex, just a very simple `if`.

Comment: I would like to keep only the lines where the number 1 and 50 are standing for. And it's indeed PAST.

Comment: @Nemo that's a separate issue then. But also easy to solve. Trim the line, split on spaces, check the first element with something like [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php). Done. Or cast to `int` and check if it is within the range [1..50]. Whatever you need.

Comment: In case of this file it will work but if I got a file where the number are not with in range from 1..50. It will not work. The numbers are random for each file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add an extra bit of logic to first find the "PART" line before writing out numbered lines:

...

```
$lines = file($newname);
$found = false;

// Loop through the array
foreach($lines as $line) { 

$seq = trim($line);

if( $seq == "PAST" )
    $found = true;

    // Find all lines starting with a number
    if ($found && preg_match('/^\d/', $seq)){ 
        # Replace all number with | 
        $seq = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $seq);
        $seq = preg_replace('/\s/',"",$seq);

        # Store in string
        $out .= $seq;
    } 
    // Read lines into file
    $f = fopen($newname, "w");
    fwrite($f, $out);
    fclose($f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something but the following should work:

```
$raw = file_get_contents($filename);
if (! $raw) {
    echo 'no valid data';
    exit;
}
$cut = strpos($raw,'PAST');
if (! $cut) {
    echo 'PAST not found in file';
    exit;
}
echo substr($raw,$cut + 5);
exit;
```

Another option as you said all files have the same structure:

```
$raw = file_get_contents($filename);
if (! $raw) {
    echo 'no valid data';
    exit;
}
$lines = explode("\n",$raw); // assume \n as the line return
$lines = array_splice($lines,13);
echo join("\n",$lines);
exit;
```